# How to check the condition render using enzyme jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

i want to check condition based on the boolean value

```
 export const Button:React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps>
 const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)

return(
<container
  color={props.color},
  border={5}
>
{loading ? <itemlist /> : props.title}
/>
)
```

I want to test if loading is true then render "<itemList/"> if not just show some title

I want to add some test cases for this

I tried this but i guess this seems to be wrong approach

```
test('check if loading is true', () => {
const isloadedProp = {
  loading: false
}

const output = mount(<Button {...ButtonProps} />)
expect(output.find(container).find(itemlist)).toBeFalsy()
expect(output.find(container).title).toBe('ABC')
```

any suggestion or answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) to gain control of `React.useState` call.

```
const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
const setLoadingMock = jest.fn();
let isLoadingState = true;
useStateSpy.mockImplementation(() => [isLoadingState, setLoadingMock]);

test('check if loading is true', () => {
  isLoadingState = true;
  // [loading, setLoading] = React.useState() will result in
  // loading = true, setLoading = setLoadingMock
  // your test code
});

test('check if loading is false', () => {
  isLoadingState = false;
  // [loading, setLoading] = React.useState() will result in
  // loading = false, setLoading = setLoading Mock
  // your test code
});
```

**UPDATED: Rewrite to using just props and not state**

As discussed, here is a solution to Button component using `isLoading` prop instead of `useState`.

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from '....'; // insert path to Container component here
import ItemList from '....'; // insert path to ItemList component here

const Button = props => {
    return (
        <Container
            color={props.color}
            border={5}
        >
            {props.isLoading ? <Itemlist /> : props.title}
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

Please mind that component names should always start with upper-case letter for React to distinguish between HTML tag and components.

Button.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Button from './Button';

const ButtonProps = {
    color: 'red',
    title: 'ABC',
};

describe('when isLoading === true', () => {
    let output;
    beforeAll(() => {
        output = mount(<Button {...ButtonProps} isLoading />);
    });

    test('ItemList is rendered', () => {
        expect(output.find('Itemlist')).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    test('title is not rendered', () => {
        expect(output.find('Container').text()).not.toContain('ABC');
    });
});

describe('when isLoading === false', () => {
    let output;
    beforeAll(() => {
        output = mount(<Button {...ButtonProps} isLoading={false} />);
    });

    test('ItemList is not rendered', () => {
        expect(output.find('Itemlist')).toHaveLength(0);
    });

    test('title is rendered', () => {
        expect(output.find('Container').text()).toContain('ABC');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't I write without spyon for usestate

Comment: Say I have prop isloading true check itemlist is to be truth, if isloading is false  is to be false and get text data

Comment: `loading` is an internal state of `Button` component, it's hard to access it. Changing it to a prop as you suggest will be much simpler to test as your component will be just reacting to props.

Comment: Can I know how to check by changing the props loading value instead of checking the state

Comment: updated the answer with another example of using just props and testing for ItemList to be present/absent and title to be shown.